# Scroll UITableView to display selected cell

Tags: ios

If I have a `UITableView` with a selected cell, how can I scroll the table so the selected cell is visible? (Or better, so that cell is in the middle of the screen).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [special method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:) for that:

```
[tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    tableView.scrollToRowIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use (if you know your indexPath selected):

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
 [yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                             animated:YES];
```

or

```
[yourTableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```